# Add Exclusion List to foreach CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, if-statement, foreach

Good day,

I am struggling to find a way to add an exclusion list to my foreach email script.

I have tried the following:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Stuff\Scripts\data.csv" 
$csvexcl = Import-csv 'C:\Stuff\Scripts\Exclusions.csv' 

foreach ($row in $csv) {
   
    if($($row.Network) -ne $csvexcl.Network)
       
        {
        if ($row.'WAN1 Status' -eq 'Ready')
              {
               Send-MailMessage -To $recipient -From $sender -Subject "$($row.Network) WAN1 is Ready!"  
                -SmtpServer $smtpserver
              }
     
        }
       
}
```

Each time I try modify the code I seem to be getting farther away from the desired result. It still keeps sending emails including the networks I am trying to exclude.

Please could someone be so kind to point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to compare one value of `$row.Network` to the entire list of `$csvexcl.Network`, then use `if ($row.Network -notin $csvexcl.Network)`

Comment: Thank you. This has answered my question.